# How to reference an object by variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following objects in an array that I would like to loop through that have the same methods.

```
var myObjects = ['a','b','c'];
```

How do I loop through this array and call the same method?

```
a.doThis();
b.doThis();
c.doThis();
```

Comment: `myObjects.forEach(obj => obj.doThis())`

Comment: Not sure gather Question. Is there `javascript` not included at OP?

Comment: "I have the following objects in an array" — Those are strings

Comment: @Quentin Well I have objects with the names in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Array.forEach(...)` loop to achieve this. It will loop through every object within the array and execute the given function.

```
var myObjects = ['a', 'b', 'c']
myObjects.forEach(o => o.doThis())
```

[Array.prototype documentation (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control)

**EDIT**: As Rob points out, if you are attempting to access actual objects called `a`, `b` and `c` in some context (assuming `this` context), you can do the following. It will depend on the context of where these objects are *actually* located. `this` should work as long as `myObjects` and your actual objects are defined within the same scope/context.

```
var myObjects = ['a', 'b', 'c']
myObjects.forEach(o => this[o].doThis())
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. The OP wants to use the strings as variable names similar to accessing object properties using square bracket notation, something like `variableObj[myObjects[0]]`.

Comment: Yeah my bad, wasn't immediately clear.

Comment: You're confusing *this* with an [*EnvironmentRecord*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-lexical-environments), which is part of an [*execution context*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-execution-contexts). A function's *this* is a parameter of an *EnvironmentRecord* and has nothing to do with scope or variables.

Comment: That's why I added the "should work" part, there was no way of knowing in what situation this code is running (a function? globally? lambda/arrow func?).